# Ubuntu 14.04 with Android 6.01 - MTP failing

Tags: 14.04, usb, android, mtp

At first I was getting an error when I was trying to access my phone's SD Storage. Then as I was trying to fix it I manage to break it even further. So, now when I plug my phone it doesn't show up. However if you run lsusb you get this output:
`Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1bcf:2883 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 046d:c048 Logitech, Inc. G9 Laser Mouse
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 22b8:2e76 Motorola PCS 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub`

Comment: This might help more to my problem:
`mtpfs -o debug`       
`Unable to open ~/.mtpz-data for reading, MTPZ disabled.Listing raw device(s)`
`Device 0 (VID=22b8 and PID=2e76) is a Motorola Moto G (ID1).`
`Found 1 device(s):`
`Motorola: Moto G (ID1) (22b8:2e76) @ bus 3, dev 10`
`Attempting to connect device`
`PTP_ERROR_IO: failed to open session, trying again after resetting USB interface`
`LIBMTP libusb: Attempt to reset device`
`Android device detected, assigning default bug flags`
`Listing File Information on Device with name: (NULL)`
`fuse: missing mountpoint parameter`

Comment: After some try with this post [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2055563) I manage to make it mount, but when I try to transport files mtpfs crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

==========================================================================

## CONCLUSION:

The problem was on the *mtpfs*, when I change it with *jmtpfs* my problem has been resolved.

The solution came from [this guide](https://linuxundich.de/gnu-linux/mit-jmtpfs-mtp-gerate-wie-das-galaxy-nexus-oder-das-samsung-galaxy-siii-in-ubuntu-mounten/) which apparently is in German, but don't worry just follow the commands.

If you can't compile the jmtpfs just run the folloing command on the terminal and skip the compile of the jmtpfs, it worked for me like that:

> sudo apt-get install jmtpfs

and then follow as normal the rest of the command on the guide and it will work just fine...

I hope that helps someone...